# IsSyncing test class quote

Tags: apex, unit-test, quote

How can I check the "IsSyncing" checkbox to true on quote to pass a validation in test class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To enable quote to opportunity sync'ing you have to set Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId to the quote id you want to sync with. [From salesforce docs:](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm)

```
public void startQuoteSync() {
         Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(); 
         opp.setId(new ID("006D000000CpOSy")); 
         opp.setSyncedQuoteId(new ID("0Q0D000000002OZ")); 
   // Invoke the update call and save the results
   try {
      SaveResult[] saveResults = binding.update(new SObject[] {opp});
      // check results and do more processing after the update call ...
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("An unexpected error has occurred." + ex.getMessage());
      return;
 }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Yes salesforce has a number of relationship fields that you would think would be editable, like the quote.issyncing but in reality are not.